# Function don't allow to return value

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to make a dialog of `alert` if the user is able to delete a `post` from the Firestore. This is how am I trying to do, I know its wrong therefor I need some support to improve my thoughts.

```
func validateDelete()->Bool{
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    db.collection("posts").whereField("UID", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
      if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
      } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {


    return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false
}
```

because I want it to use it like this:

```
enum ActiveAlert {
    case delete, denied
}

struct ToggleView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var activeAlert: ActiveAlert = .delete

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            if validateDelete {
                self.activeAlert = .delete
            } else {
                self.activeAlert = .denied
            }
            self.showAlert = true
        }) {
            Text("Show random alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            switch activeAlert {
            case .delete:
                Alert(title: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this?"), message: Text("There is no undo"), primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
 document.reference.delete()
                    print("Deleting...")
            }, secondaryButton: .cancel())
            case .denied:
                return Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("you don't have permission to delete this"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return from inside a closure like you are trying to do so instead you should use a completion handler that gets called from inside the function.

```
func validateDelete(completion: @escaping (Bool)-> Void) {
```

then instead of doing `return true //or false` you do `completion(true)`

and when calling the function you can use it like this

```
validateDelete { flag in
    if flag {
        self.activeAlert = .delete
    } else {
        self.activeAlert = .denied
    }
}
```

I don't use firebase but I guess the whole function would look something like this

```
func validateDelete(completion: @escaping (Bool)-> Void) {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    db.collection("posts").whereField("UID", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        completion(false)
    } else {
        let exists = querySnapshot!.documents.count > 0
        completion(exists)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is how am I trying to do, but I am getting this error: `Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'`

Comment: I think it should be like this? `func validateDelete(completion: @escaping (Bool)-> Void) {`

Comment: Very likely, I wasn't able to test my code in a reliable way

Comment: Thanks again, I have last question. how can I change the calling of this function if I pass a value to the `validateDelete` function? like -> `func validateDelete(completion: @escaping (Bool)-> Void,msg:String) {` ? with `validateDelete { flag in` does not work at all.

Comment: `func validateDelete(msg: String, completion:...` and then `validateDelete(someString) { flag in ...`

Comment: It did not work as expected, may I Chat with you please about this topic? then I will surely  accept the answer